# Applying filters to headers in huge csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I am working with the csv file with size approx 500MB. https://s3.amazonaws.com/GooglePlayStore/GooglePlayStats.zip

Opening the above csv file in excel causes wrong data to be displayed under wrong column headers (may be due to large size of csv). Opening with EM editor doesn't allow me to align the columns data and to remove entire columns from the csv file.

what is my best way to use this csv in a user friendly way (aligning the data in columns and deleting columns of no interest)

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option is to use an editor that's been designed for "large csv's". They tend to load the CSV data on demand from the source file, rather than reading it all into memory and processing it. Plus a CSV editor will have less processing overhead compared to Excel as they are 10000000x dumber.

Quick google for "large csv editor" should get you going. Such as http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/ (randomly selected, not endorsed)